# Google Cloud Build Docker build-arg not respected

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm having a problem with Google Cloud Build where the docker build command doesn't seem to be accepting the build-arg option, even though this same command works as expected on local:

Dockerfile:

```
ARG ASSETS_ENV=development
RUN echo "ASSETS_ENV is ${ASSETS_ENV}"
```

Build Command:

```
docker build --build-arg="ASSETS_ENV=production" .
```

Result on local:

```
ASSETS_ENV is production
```

Result on Cloud Build:

```
ASSETS_ENV is development
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok the fix was in the cloud build yaml config:

Before:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '--build-arg="ASSETS_ENV=production"', '.']
```

After:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'docker build --build-arg="ASSETS_ENV=production" .']
```

Comment: Btw, does anyone know why the former solution doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried passing `build-arg` in two separate args? as in `args: [ "build", "--build-arg", "ASSET_ENV=production", ...]`. I have a similar setup and it works. 
`args: ["build","--build-arg", "TF2_BASE_IMAGE=${_TF2_BASE_IMAGE}" ...]`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who defines their steps like this:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args:
  - build
  - foo
  - bar
```

The comment from [@nader-ghanbari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938246/nader-ghanbari) worked for me:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args:
  - build
  - --build-arg
  - TF2_BASE_IMAGE=${_TF2_BASE_IMAGE}
```