# How can I use a non-exec entrypoint for Kaniko in Google Cloud Build (to enable build arg definition)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, kaniko

The [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-kaniko-build-container-images-in-kubernetes-and-google-container-builder-even-without-root-access) for using Kaniko in GCB use the `exec` form of the kaniko project builder, like this:

```
  - id: 'Build (with Kaniko Cache)'
    name: 'gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest'
    args:
      - --destination=$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$SHORT_SHA
      - --cache=true
      - --cache-ttl=6h
```

But I'm using it to replace a docker build, in which I circumvent the `exec` form of usage in order to inject a build arg (an access token from the Secret Manager) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65302542/how-do-i-use-google-secrets-manager-to-create-a-docker-arg-in-google-cloud-build) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56732084/google-cloud-build-docker-build-arg-not-respected).

```
  - id: 'Build'
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        docker build --cache-from $_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$SHORT_SHA --build-arg PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_GITHUB=$(cat decrypted-pat.txt) -t $_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$SHORT_SHA .
```

I've tried defining a `bash` entrypoint but that's not found so I'm stuck. Is it even possible to run the non-exec form?

*Note: It is possible to access the secret in a file within the container instead of via a build arg, but that would mean changing the setup for my developers to all have that secret file in order to build their development images locally, which I could, but really don't want, to do.*

Comment: There is example of docker cloud builder `args` syntax here: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#args. Maybe you should try to use similar approach?

Comment: @vitooh those documents show the `exec` form that needs to be worked around, since it doesn't allow dynamic construction of the build args.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it using `docker run`:

```yaml
- id: Build
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args:
  - -c
  - |
   docker run \
      --network=cloudbuild \
      -v /workspace:/workspace \
        gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest \
          --dockerfile /workspace/Dockerfile \
          --build-arg=GITHUBTOKEN=$$GITHUBTOKEN \
          --destination=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/myapp:$SHORT_SHA \
          --cache=true \
          --context dir:///workspace/
  secretEnv: ['GITHUBTOKEN']

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/github_machine_user_pat/versions/latest
      env: GITHUBTOKEN
```

Comment: When I asked the question, the availableSecrets field wasn't actually available to cloudbuild (or if it was, it wasn't documented). But they're moving fast and in sensible directions, so this is definitely now the correct answer, thanks Fábio.

Answer (score 0):

The Kaniko executor image provides the `--build-arg` flag to pass in ARG values at build time, similarly to Docker. You'll find the full list of additional flags [here](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#additional-flags).

Given that, you'll be able to run your build like so:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: [ '-c', "gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret=secret-name --format='get(payload.data)' | tr '_-' '/+' | base64 -d > decrypted-pat.txt" ]
- name: 'gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest'
  args:
  - --destination=$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$SHORT_SHA
  - --cache=true
  - --cache-ttl=6h
  - --build-arg=PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_GITHUB=$(cat decrypted-pat.txt)
```

Comment: `$(cat decrypted-pat.txt)` won't work since it is not running within a shell

Comment: There is no shell entrypoint for kaniko. It operates [from a scratch image](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/blob/8710ce3311be79a331a325d57d13a1b9df6aa5a6/deploy/Dockerfile#L47).